# How is it possible that Ū = ∅?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I thought Ū = U - U = {x | x ∈ U and x ∉ U}. But since ∅ belongs to every set, including U, ∅ ∉ U is false, meaning Ū = ∅ is false.

Comment: The emptyset is open and closed. So $\overline{\emptyset}=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\emptyset$ is not an element of every set. It is only a subset of every set.